# SSRS text and calculation

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

In SSRS in one of my tables cells I have the following calculation:

```
=((SUM(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value)) / 2000)
```

Is there anyway to then add a T to the value that this returns denoteing that it is Tons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=CStr(((SUM(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value)) / 2000)) + "T"